# HBase rowkey which includes timestamp

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I would like to whether it is bad to have rowkeys like the following:

username-timestamp

This rows would be read from MapReduce jobs and will be put using java client API. Also, a subset would be selected using STARTROW, ENDROW.

On one side this seems convinient for my usecase since I can scan for specific interval and rows arebmostly subsequent for MR job, while on the other I read that it is good to avoid long rowkeys and hotspoting.

Is there really a problem with this design and how to overcome it?

I'm new to HBase so any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general advice is to avoid monotonically increasing row keys. To that purpose, some software tools include a so called "salt" to the row key, which hashes the keys across regions. A discussion can be found here: http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/rowkey.design.html. And here: https://phoenix.apache.org/salted.html. You can also look at Apache Trafodion http://trafodion.apache.org/, which uses row key salting to distribute SQL-like primary keys.

Comment: Could you please explain why is this good in case of MapReduce jobs? My understanding is that the keys I mentioned lead to better data locality for MR jobs, which leads to less scan time. Am I wrong? Also, how would you perform salting in my case, should I prepend salt value at the begining? For example a-username-timestamp, b-username-timestamp?

Comment: Also, won't this break STARTROW ENDROW scan?

Comment: The salt should be at the beginning - and yes, the drawback is that you cannot easily do a range scan over a large area. You will have to issue a scan per salt bucket, or use filters.